# mysql: select join table with latest record for both table

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

This question has been asked at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54471905/mysql-join-2-table-with-latest-record-only) as well.

i had 2 table, tableA and tableB looking like this:

**tableA:**

[image]

**tableB:**

[image]

i manage to get the latest record by auto increment id by using the following sql for tableA and tableB:

```
SELECT *
FROM tableA 
WHERE id IN (SELECT MAX(id) AS id
             FROM tableA 
             GROUP BY social_num) 


SELECT *
FROM tableB 
WHERE id IN (SELECT MAX(id) AS id
             FROM tableB 
             GROUP BY social_num)
```

how to join them together, so that, i get the latest record on tableA and latest record on tableB link by social_num?
i tried following sql, it work:

```
SELECT *
FROM tableA 
LEFT JOIN tableB ON tableA.social_num = tableB.social_num
WHERE tableA.id IN (SELECT MAX(id) AS id
             FROM tableA 
             GROUP BY social_num) 
AND
tableB.id IN (SELECT MAX(id) AS id
             FROM tableB 
             GROUP BY social_num)
```

but how do i show all of other user from tableA togather as well, like **Morris Q**

**DDL Information**

```
CREATE TABLE `tableA` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fullname` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `social_num` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=13 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

/*Data for the table `tableA` */

insert  into `tableA`(`id`,`fullname`,`social_num`,`email`) values (1,'David J','1155','davidj@gmail.com'),(2,'Brian H','2244','brianh@gmail.com'),(3,'Hawkins M','6677','hawkins@gmail.com'),(4,'Marry K','7122','marry@gmail.com'),(5,'Utah O','9123','utah@gmail.com'),(6,'James L','1266','james@gmail.com'),(7,'David J','1155','david@hotmail.com'),(8,'Marry K','7122','marry@gmail.com'),(9,'Johnson E','1180','johnson@gmail.com'),(10,'Hawkins M','6677','hawkins@yahoo.com'),(11,'Morris Q','1461','morris@gmail.com'),(12,'David J','1155','david@yahoo.com');

CREATE TABLE `tableB` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fullname` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `social_num` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone_num` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fav_color` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

/*Data for the table `tableB` */

insert  into `tableB`(`id`,`fullname`,`social_num`,`phone_num`,`fav_color`) values (1,'Brian H','2244','912-112-1231','blue'),(2,'Johnson E','1180','912-221-5512','red'),(3,'David J','1155','812-231-6125','green'),(4,'Utah O','9123','741-661-3125','red'),(5,'Hawkins M','6677','881-331-6612','blue'),(6,'James L','1266','934-513-5132','yellow'),(7,'Brian H','2244','785-513-9821','green'),(8,'David J','1155','960-231-5151','black'),(9,'Hawkins M','6677','135-661-3516','red');
```

Any help would be great, im using mysql 5.5

Comment: Can you provide how the resulting table should look like when Morris Q is counted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope that query is selfexplanatory enough.

```
SELECT a.*, b.*
  FROM 
       (SELECT MAX(w.id) AS id
             , w.social_num
          FROM tableA AS w
         GROUP BY w.social_num
       ) AS maxa
  LEFT JOIN 
       (SELECT MAX(z.id) AS id
             , z.social_num
          FROM tableB AS z
         GROUP BY z.social_num
       ) AS maxb  ON maxb.social_num = maxa.social_num
  JOIN tableA       AS a  ON a.id = maxa.id
  LEFT JOIN tableB  AS b  ON b.id = maxb.id
;
```

The only assumption I've made is that persons from `tableB` are the subset of persons in the `tableA` and there is no persons listed in the `table B` and not in the `tableA`. Otherwise the `FULL OUTER JOIN` not implemented by mysql should be emulated by `UNION`.